# Entity Framework Generic Repository Implementation with IQuarable

Tags: entity-framework-4

Entity Framework has changed drastically since they have introduced version 1. EF 4.1 has improved Code First and Fluent mappings which are really impressive. However, I have a worry about complex query implementations on EF 4.1 because it depends on DbContext strongly. Entity SQL and Linq to Entities keep on changing it's behavior with SQL queries. I feel we need a strong Query mechanism like HQL or Criteria to overcome this. What you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many modern .NET ORMs provide an IQueryProvider implementation (including NHibernate). I choose to remove the direct dependency on EF by using POCO T4 template, then modifying it to generate an interface (IMyRepository) that returns plain IQueryables instead of ObjectSets. The underlying implementation of IMyRepository using a ObjectContext. If we decide to move away from EntityFramework, we can just change the implementation of IMyRepository to use someone else's LINQ IQueryProvider.

Further, this allows us to work in a distributed scenario. For example, one implementation of IMyRepository lives on the client and uses DataServiceClient (WCF Data Services) to call out to the server, which has a different implementation of IMyRepository, which uses Entity Framework directly.

In the case of Code First, this is also fairly easy to do. Your classes are already POCOs...so just make your DbContext implement an interface that returns IQueryables instead of DbSets.

I personally then inject the IMyRepository using dependency injection.

Comment: However, For instance, if we want to join a query with two POCOs then we want use DbContext in one repository. isnt it ?

Comment: I don't understand why that would make a difference? from i in repo.MyEntity1s from j in repo.MyEntity2s....etc.

Comment: Yes. I got it now. Thanks for the explanation. I do agree with IQuerable implementation we need to provide following implementation and separate method for Loading Type as follows.

Answer (score 0):

My Generic repository Looks like follows

```
public class Repository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>: IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> where TEntity : class
{
    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery()
    {
        return this.UnitOfWork.GetQuery<TEntity>();
    }       
    public IQueryable<T> LoadType<T>() where T : class
    {
        return this.UnitOfWork.GetQuery<T>();
    }
}
```

And My Unit of Work goes here

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the query.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">The type of the entity.</typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery<TEntity>() where TEntity:class 
    {
        return this.DbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }        
}
```